# Pseudo code needed if possible?

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering if I could have some pseudo code for working out the following

i need to loop through a 2d array(the method i am working on takes an int). It starts at the position of the value passed in and then goes down until it hits the same value on the left hand side. As its doing this every int in the 2d array is added to a local variable. 
Now we are at position (x,x) i guess? Then from here i need to loop across to the right adding all variables to the same previous local var and then return that number

The 2d array for illustration purposed looks something like this for example

```
1 2 3 4 
2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 
3 2 1 4
```

So if i were to pass in 2 we would start at the number 3 top line i guess, we would loop down until position 3,3 ( 3 + 4 + 3) and then loop to the right until the end (+ 4)

those numbers would be added and returned.

I hope pseudo code is possible and I haven't just given it already myself lol (thus proving i cant actually code it lol :D )

if not any examples you could provide me with that my help me out :D

thanks guys

Comment: well it is semi homework, its part of an assignmnet yes but this is an approach to solving the problem i have taken on my own, not something that was explicitly set for us to follow and do

Comment: To me this seems like a difficult way to solve a simple problem. But I'm not sure about your array of edges there. How do I read it? Are the edges one-way, and should only the edges going from the node be counted? Otherwise your example array contradicts itself. To me it says node 3 has 4 edges going to node 2, but node 2 has 2 edges going to node 3.

Comment: yes it really is difficult but im sure its the only way, my example was just random numbers but yes you are reading it correctly, if you think of each position of the 2d array as a node (so each index along the top) and each index along the side. A node can connect to itself, a real one (| = new line
)

0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 |
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 |
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 |
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 |
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 |
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 |
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 |
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this pseudocode should do what you're looking for:

```
array[][] := ...
position := ...
sum := 0

//add the contents of the outer array
for i := 0 to array.length do
    sum := sum + array[i][position]

    //if we're at (pos, pos) then start looping over the inner array
    if i = position then

        //note we start at pos + 1 so as not to count array[i][position] twice
        for j := position + 1 to array[j].length do
            sum := sum + array[i][j]
        end

        break from loop  

    end
end
```

Comment: No problem. You'll probably want to add some extra error handling code when you implement it to ensure that the position the method takes is within the bounds of the array (e.g. less that array.length).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, I assume this is just an assignment.
If you are looping to the right, shouldn't 1 be included if not the 2 as well?

i.e. then loop to the right until the end (+1 + 4)

Comment: yes this is an assignmnet, but this is kind of a side issue that i need to solve in order to achieve the assignment, i need to determine if each node in a graph has even edges. So if i am checking node 3. Node 3 has edges with 
(3,0)(3,1)(3,2)(3,3(not sure about this one))(4,3)

dont no if that clears it up at all?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether you store the columns or the rows of matrix. Assuming you have a `n * n` size matrix and you store the rows, so

```
A = [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4], [3,2,1,4]]
```

and the starting point is `i`, you should go from the array no. `m = i div n` (the integer part of the division, rounding down), and inside the array, the staring element should be the no. `p = i mod n` (the modulus). And from that point, you can select every array from `m` to `n`, and in every array, the `p`th element, until the most recent element is the same as your original.

In Java-like code:

```
int n = 4;
int[][] A = new int[n][n];
... // initialize A

int sumValues(int i) { 
    int original = A[i/n][i%n];   
    int sum = original;
    int p = i % n;

    for (m = i/n + 1, m<n, ++m) {
        if (A[m][p] != orginal) sum += A[m][p];
        else break;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

If you are storing the columns, so

```
A = [[1,2,1,3], [2,3,2,2], [3,4,3,1], [4,5,4,4]]
```

then `m` and `p` are inversed, meaning that from `A` you should select array no. `m = i mod n` and inside that array, element no. `p = i div n`. After this, you stay in your selected array, and just increase `p` until `A[m][p]` equals to the originally selected value.

In Java-like code:

```
int n = 4;
int[][] A = new int[n][n];
... // initialize A

int sumValues(int i) { 
    int original = A[i%n][i/n];   
    int sum = original;
    int p = i / n;

    for (p = i/n +1, p<n, ++p) {
        if (A[m][p] != orginal) sum += A[m][p];
        else break;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

But correct me, if I'm wrong :)